# Pass data from child widget to the parent widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Dashboard Widget whose body is like this:

I want to pass data from the child widget DashboardGrid(Check at the end of the Code block) to this parent widget. How do I do it?

```dart
    body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
      SizedBox(
      height: 20,
    ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "Categories",
                    style:  TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
     
                ],
              ),
              IconButton(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                icon: new Icon(Icons.search, color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,),
                onPressed: () {},
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 40,
        ),
DashboardGrid(),
])
```

Comment: just pass a function as argument to DashboardGrid() from parent , then call that function by passing the required data you want to pass . Since the function is defined in Parent widget class, you can do you evaluation of data with in that function

Answer (score 0):

With callback.

Create a function inside `DashboardGrid`

```
class DashboardGrid extends StatelessWidget {

final Function(String) callback;

DashboardGrid({this.callback});

....
```

Then inside the column you will instantiate it with the function

```
[
...,
DashboardGrid(callback:(String value)=>print(value));
]
```

When you want to pass that data inside `DashboardGrid`, just call the function

```
void passTheData(String data) => callback(data);
```

example is with `String` but you can pass any data.

Answer (score 0):

If your child widget lives under the same widget tree, you can take advantage of `Notification` to bubble up data.

First, create notifications for what you need. You can either create **one** notification or an abstract `Notification` with multiple concrete ones. For this example, I'll assume you want to handle different notifications.

```
abstract class MyNotification extends Notification {}

class SomethingHappened extends MyNotification {}

class NothingHappened extends MyNotification {}
```

Then you can handle all notifications for that type in the parent widget:

```
class ParentWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NotificationListener<MyNotification>(
      onNotification: (notification) {
        // Handle your notification
        return true;
      },
      child: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

Or pick individual ones:

```
class ParentWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NotificationListener<MyNotification>(
      onNotification: (notification) {
        if(notification is SomethingHappened){
          // Handle 
        } else if(notification is NothingHappened){
          // Handle
        }
        return true;
      },
      child: Container(),
    );
  }
```

To emit the notification from your child widget, you just need to call `T().dispatch(context)` where `T` is your `Notification` type. For example, `SomethingHappened().dispatch(context);`. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

For fixing that, there are two ways. The first way is to create a GlobalKey(https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html) and pass it as a parameter to the child widget. And the second way is to create a global variable for the parent state and use it in the child state.